# Serverless apiKey error API Keys must be strings

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, serverless-framework

I have a requirement to create a `usagePlan` for an endpoint with two different `apiKeys`.

This is the piece of config that gives me a lot of headache:

```
apiKeys:
    - android:
        - android
        - ${self:provider.stage}-android
    - ios:
        - ios
        - ${self:provider.stage}-ios
  usagePlan:
    - android:
        quota:
          limit: 500
          offset: 2
          period: MONTH
        throttle:
          burstLimit: 20
          rateLimit: 10
    - ios:
        quota:
          limit: 5000
          offset: 1
          period: MONTH
        throttle:
          burstLimit: 200
          rateLimit: 100
```

This is taken from the `serverless` docs from [here](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#setting-api-keys-for-your-rest-api)

I tried all the varieties from the docs and all the possibilities but one give me the following error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

API Keys must be strings
```

And the one that works look like this:

```
apiKeys:
 - android
 - ios
usagePlan:
  ...
```

Which doesn't work for me because I need to have 2 keys that are parametrised with the environment name.

I tried all the variations from the docs and it seems nothing works.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue by updating the serverless framework to the most current version (1.49.0 in my case) using

```
npm install serverless@1.49.0 -g
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I did but at the time of the update it was the version 1.48.0 :)